# In Shiny, loading data, then preprocessing to the global environment, then showing UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a Shiny app that populates the UI based on the values of a data and preprocessing of the same data. This preprocessing also provides some objects to the server.R.  This app works fine as long as the data is loaded and preprocessed before initiating the ui.R and server.R. The current structure is

1. data_preprocessing.R loads data from local machine
2. source(data_preprocessing.R) to load both into ui.R and server.R
3. run app.R

This toy code exemplifies this scenario:

```
# Scenario A
# run on local machine

df <- mtcars
# processe
min.y <- min(df$mpg)
max.y <- max(df$mpg)
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "y.value",
        label = "Filter mpg",
        min = min.y,
        max = max.y,
        value = c(mean.y - 1, mean.y + 1),
        step = 0.5
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))


server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_df <- reactive({
    df[which(df$mpg >= input$y.value[1] & df$mpg <= input$y.value[2]), ]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(filtered_df(), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problem arises now when I want to generalize this approach to a scenario where the user uploads a dataset once in one rudimentary user interface (e.g. a tab in ui.R), and only then the main user interface in ui.R launches. Additionally, the preprocessing provides several objects for the server. Structure of the code would look something like the following (this does not actually work...):

```
# Scenario B
# run in the Internet

# df <- mtcars
# # processe
# min.y <- min(df$mpg)
# max.y <- max(df$mpg)
# mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                     label = "Process this data")
        #actionButton("submit", label = "Submit")

      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "y.value",
          label = "Filter mpg",
          min = min.y,
          max = max.y,
          value = c(mean.y - 1, mean.y + 1),
          step = 0.5
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$go, {

    inFile <- input$file1 

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    # read this file in via a browser!
    #df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    # for this example load mtcars
    df <- mtcars

    # process
    min.y <- min(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
    max.y <- max(df$mpg)  # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
    mean.y <- mean(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!

    df # PREFERABLY, SHOULD ALSO BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!

  })


  filtered_df <- reactive({

    df1 <- mydata()
    df1[which(df1$mpg >= input$y.value[1] & df1$mpg <= input$y.value[2]), ]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(filtered_df(), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I could probably store all preprocessed objects as reactive objects, but that will quickly make the code unwieldy.

An "easy" solution is if I could somehow make all these preprocessing objects available in the global environment. Many of them are only needed for calculation once. I tried using "<<-" for the relevant objects but that does not work. R protests with "Error in <<-: cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'".

Accordingly, ideas of how to solve this problem?

UPDATE (2019-07-19) based on @MrGumble input:

The global environment is global to all users on the same app. So if user 1 uploads a data set on his jellybean consumption and saves min.y, max.y and mean.y to the global environment, followed by user 2 starting the app, then both users will be presented with these data! When user 2 then uploads her data set on student performances, it overwrites user 1's data! What a mess!

You are right! So instead of the global environment it should be saved in the session environment so that all functions within that session can use it.

A)  What does the session argument do? I Google around but could not find a clear answer.

B)  Using “<<-”

Using “<<-“ is not working. I have tried defining it within the server function as well as outside of it. But none works. Do you see what is wrong?

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        # fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        #           accept = c(
        #             "text/csv",
        #             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        #             ".csv")
        # ),
        # tags$hr(),
        # checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                     label = "Process this data")
        #actionButton("submit", label = "Submit")

      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "y.value",
          label = "Filter mpg",
          min = 1,
          max = 30,
          value = c(10 - 1, 15 + 1),
          step = 0.5
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df2 <- NA

  # # define reactivevalues
  # min.y <- reactiveVal()
  # max.y <- reactiveVal()

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$go, {


    df # PREFERABLY, SHOULD ALSO BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!

  })

  # update min max when the data loads
  observeEvent(input$go, {

    df2 <<- mydata()
  })




  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(df2, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

C)  Does it matter for what is displayed in the user interface if we run the server function or the ui function first? I guess not but I have a lurking feeling that it might.

D) Lastly, and most importantly, based on your comments I have updated my code. The ui fails to capture min.y and max.y

```
# Scenario C
# run in the Internet


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # define reactivevalues
  min.y <- reactiveVal()
  max.y <- reactiveVal()

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$go, {

    inFile <- input$file1 

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    # read this file in via a browser!
    #df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    # for this example load mtcars
    df <- mtcars

    # # process
    # min.y <- min(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
    # max.y <- max(df$mpg)  # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
    # mean.y <- mean(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
    # 
    df # PREFERABLY, SHOULD ALSO BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!

  })

  # update min max when the data loads
  observeEvent(mydata, {
    min.y(min(mydata()$mpg))
    max.y(max(mydata()$mpg))
  })


  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "go", min=min.y(), max=max.y())
  })


  filtered_df <- reactive({

    df1 <- mydata()
    df1[which(df1$mpg >= input$y.value[1] & df1$mpg <= input$y.value[2]), ]
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(filtered_df(), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })


}


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                     label = "Process this data")
        #actionButton("submit", label = "Submit")

      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "y.value",
          label = "Filter mpg",
          min = min.y,
          max = max.y,
          value = c(10 - 1, 15 + 1),
          step = 0.5
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )
)



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The `server` and `ui` functions are run at the same time; `ui` is however run with what it is given before any of the reactives in the `server`-function are executed. Hence the variables in your `ui`-function are not exposed to the variables in `server`. So you will need a starting default, and then update your ui after a dataset is loaded.

Comment: ok, makes sense re server and ui relationship. Would you have any additional input on my follow-up D)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by "attacking" your assumptions on

```
# process
min.y <- min(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
max.y <- max(df$mpg)  # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg) # SHOULD BE MADE AVAILABLE IN THE GLOBAL ENVIROMENT SO ui CAN USE IT!
```

The global environment is *global to all users on the same app*. So if user 1 uploads a data set on his jellybean consumption and saves `min.y`, `max.y` and `mean.y` to the global environment, followed by user 2 starting the app, then both users will be presented with these data! When user 2 then uploads her data set on student performances, it overwrites user 1's data! What a mess!

So, data in global environment <strike>stays constant</strike> is shared across all sessions! It's useful for pre-loading data that is constant throughout all uses.

If you want to share data *within* your session, put the variable within the `server`-function:

```
constant.var <- readRDS('some-precalculation.rds')

server <- function(input, output) {
  my_users_name <- ''
  observeEvent(input$txtName, {
    my_users_name <<- input$txtName
  })
}
```

In your code `mydata` *is unique* to the session. It's defined within `server`.

When you want to use `min.y` in the UI, the definition of `ui` does not change throughout the usage of the app. I believe it is only execute once, when `runApp()` starts. After that, you can change `min.y` all you want and the UI doesn't change. (In my example above, notice that I use `<<-` to assign a value to a variable defined in a outer scope. Do this to re-define `min.y` in the global environment.)

How do you update the range of your slider?

1) Declare your limits as reactive variables. This allows Shiny to recognise when to update something.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  min.y <- reactiveVal()
  max.y <- reactiveVal()
}
```

2) `min.y` and `max.y` are only updated when the uploaded dataset is updated:

```
observeEvent(mydata, {
  min.y(min(mydata()$mpg))
  max.y(max(mydata()$mpg))
})
```

In fact, we can reduce 1) and 2) to be directly reactives on the uploaded data set:

```
mydata <- reactiveVal(data.frame())
observeEvent(input$go, {
  if (is.null(input$file1))
    return(NULL) 
  df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header=input$header)
  # do some checking?
  mydata(df)
})
min.y <- reactive(min(mydata()$mpg))
max.y <- reactive(max(mydata()$mpg))
```

I've updated the routine, so the `mydata` is a reactive that only gets updated when everything is checked and OK. In your code, if `input$file1` is `NULL`, the reactive `mydata` will be updated to `NULL` causing issues downstream when you expect it to be a data frame.

So, how to update the UI? See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/updateSliderInput.html
Which leads us to the following. First update your `server`-function to accept the `session` argument:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
```

and then react to an updated min and max:

```
observe({
  updateSliderInput(session, "y.value", min=min.y(), max=max.y())
})
```

Of cause, if you only use `min.y` and `max.y` for updating the slider, you can do away with `min.y` and `max.y` reactives as:

```
observe({
  df <- mydata()
  if (is.null(df) || nrow(df) == 0)
    return()

  updateSliderInput(session, "y.value", min=min(df$mpg), max=max(df$mpg))
})
```

but that is a matter of taste and modularisation of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrGumble! I have updated my question based on your input. I have some followups you or anyone else could guide me with.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting it and/or marking the answer as the correct answer. Follow-up questions should ideally be a new question (if my comment didn't help you though).

Comment: Thanks, @MrGumble, for the reminder. Your input is useful so I have upvoted it. As per my update, there remain some questions. I could post my follow-up question A) to C) as new question, but D) remains to fully answer this post. Would you have any additional input on D)? Would be much appriciated.

Comment: @Adel, as per my comment on your question, the `min.y` and `max.y` variables defined in the `server`-function are not within the namescope that the `ui`-function can access. Consider this: `ui` is run at start-up; how can it access min and max y values, based on data uploaded *after* it has run? Hence, provide meaningful default values (just literal scalar values).

Comment: ok, that makes sense of course to provide defaults in the UI that get updates after data is uploaded.  But my original question was if one could avoid that altogether by either (1) updating variables outside the server and ui, or (2) connect two servers (one for preprocessing and other for displaying). The example I provided is a toy example, the original Shiny app has more that 20 variables that have to update given the uploaded data. The strategy you propose is a useful one, albeit I am wondering if there is an easier one

Comment: In a Shiny app, variables defined outside of the `server` and `ui`-functions are shared across all sessions. An alternate strategy could be to divide your workflow into separate stages, an upload-data stage and a present-and-statistics stage. The latter controls could be dynamically loaded once data has been uploaded and checked.

Comment: Right, that would be something closer to how I am thinking about solving the problem. Would this solution involve having two server functions, or is it simply one server with reactive still? Could you please point me to an example?

Comment: I think you should take some time to read up on how Shiny works and consider the workflow presented to the user. As for reading, I suggest you look at these articles, http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html, http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestions. Will have a look and get back to this question.

Comment: Do not update your question. Instead, ask a new question.